# Using `go` with fish shell

Tags: go, fish

I am struggling with running `go` in the **fish shell**.

A) I followed the installation procedure and installed `go` as specified in the [documentation](https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.12.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz)

However, when I run `go version`, I am getting a fatal error:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

When I initialize the git by `git init`, I receive another error:

```
error: pathspec 'version' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I have the paths configured in my fish **config** as follows:

```
set -gx GOPATH /home/<user>/go
set -gx PATH $PATH /usr/local/bin/go $GOPATH/bin
```

where `/usr/local/bin/go` is an output of `which go` in both `bash` and `fish`

Running it like `bash -c 'go version'`, however, **works without any problems** (even without the git directory).

B) Also tried `gofish` and `dnf` to install go, the same results

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Additional info:

- Fish version: `fish, version 3.0.2`
- Operating system: `Linux t460s 5.0.13-300.fc30.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: You almost certainly have some kind of shell alias for "go" and you're running that and not the go executable. Try `which go`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I already mentioned the output of `which go` in the question:

> "where /usr/local/bin/go is an output of which go in both bash and fish"

Comment: Could this be some kind of alias that is used instead? The error message is an error from the `git` binary. Take a look in your file `~/.config/fish/config.fish` and see if you find an alias there. If you do not find anything there look at the files in `~/.config/fish/` and subfolders.

Comment: Oh my ... @mbuechmann completely correct. It was aliased to `git checkout` (facepalm, 2 hours spent by this thing). I had no idea that the `which` command does not catch that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'll add this as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be some kind of alias that is used instead? The error message is an error from the git binary.

Take a look in your file ~/.config/fish/config.fish and see if you find an alias there. If you do not find anything there look at the files in ~/.config/fish/ and subfolders.

Comment: Or see what comes up with `type -a go`